# Adsense GDPR consent message - add logo

Tags: adsense

I have enabled the Adsense GDPR consent message on my site - it works fine.  However I'd like to customize it by adding my logo.

Google say:

**Add a logo to a site message**

- *Sign in to your AdSense account.*
- *Click Privacy & messaging.*
- *Click GDPR.*
- *In the list of messages, click Edit in the row with the message you want to edit.*
- *Click Header in the menu sidebar.*
- **Turn on the Logo toggle to automatically display your site's logo in your message.**
- *Click Apply style to update the message.*
- *If no logo is found, turn off the Logo toggle. Leaving the toggle turned on when there is no logo to display may prevent you from being
  able to publish the message.*

In my case the site logo is not found and I can't find where or how to add one.

Answer (score 1):

Click: > Privacy & messaging > GDPR > Messages > [message style] Edit > Site settings > edit > Logo > Add

[image]